# Windows 10 extend display

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I just updated my laptop to Windows 10. Got an Asus R750J laptop running GeForce GT750m, which was running fine in Win8.1.

I now have problem extending my display to a second monitor. I have the options connecting to a second monitor via HDMI or mini-displayport. The second monitor can now mirror fine and has no issue. However, I tried to extend the display and then Windows doesn't seem to detect the 2nd monitor, so I can't extend it.

Looked at the device manager and made sure that the driver was installed. I also manually downloaded the driver from Nvidia and still no dice.

Has anyone got any issue with extending display in windows 10?

Update: I took another look at the drivers that I downloaded when I bought my laptop. I now suspect it may be related to an Intel SharkBay driver that may require re-installing. I have to give it a try when I get home. The only concern I have is that that particular driver doesn't appear to have a Windows 10 version. I hope it isn't the case of waiting for the new driver release.

Comment: Have you tried pressing WINDOWS+P and selecting "extend"?

Comment: You said that you tried to extend it and it didn't display anything, so does the monitor go into powersave mode?  Also when you have connected your external monitor, when you go into the Display settings screen & click "Detect", does it recognise the additional monitor has been connected?

Comment: @James I didn't say it didn't display anything. When I tried to detect the 2nd monitor, Windows said it can't detect and doesn't give me the option to extend. i.e. I can only get the first monitor to mirror to the 2nd one.

Comment: @EthanBierlein I tried Windows+P and also went thru Control Panel -> display, and there was no luck either.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I have fixed the problem.

I reinstalled the old Intel HD graphic driver and the problem has been resolved straight away.

Found some links about the latest Windows 10 drivers.

https://communities.intel.com/thread/75672
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25150/Intel-Iris-Iris-Pro-and-HD-Graphics-Production-Driver-for-Windows-10-64-bit

Going to install it now and see if it's even better.

Answer (score 1):

Mulptiple attempts at the Windows + P key and Fn+F8 (display options) didn't work either.  Was about to download latest driver for windows 10 but instead went to Device Manager, under Display adaptors, saw the outdated Intel HD graphics 4600 card and since that didn't quite match with the latest graphics driver for Windows 10 I found earlier, didn't download the one I found online but right-clicked and updated it. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just found the second video card taht wasn't working in device manager, uninstalled it, then reinstalled the driver, and worked almost straight away.

Happy days.